# Dart equivalent of anonymous closures

Tags: javascript, closures, dart

Is there something similar to [anonymous closures](http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth.html) in Dart? Or is this feature unnecessary with OOP? Is there a workaround?

Thanks.

Comment: To the person who voted to close this question, could you please explain why this question is bad and what I should do to improve?

Comment: The javascript patterns in the link seem to be workarounds for javascript's lack of library syntax. Dart has libraries built in, why not just use those?

Comment: @GregLowe Good point. I was just asking because I was curious if it existed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do the same thing in Dart.

For instance :

```dart
main() {
  (() => print('hello'))();
}
```

That said those kind of anonymous closures are almost useless because Dart has [lexical scope](https://www.dartlang.org/docs/dart-up-and-running/contents/ch02.html#ch02-lexical-scope) and you have to run Dart code inside a `main` function.

Comment: What about importing scripts into the closure? Does it work the same way?

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: In javascript anonymous closures, to use global objects, it is necessary to import them (see the link in the question). Is it required in dart, and if so, how does it work?

Comment: @cloudcoder2000 No, Dart has lexical closures. See https://www.dartlang.org/docs/dart-up-and-running/contents/ch02.html#ch02-functions-lexical-closures

Comment: @Ganymede I know it has lexical closures, but we're talking about anonymous closures. Are you saying that they work the same way?

Comment: Yes, Dart even has anonymous closures. For example, `f(x) => () { return x; };`... `f` returns an anonymous closure and `f(42)()` returns `42`.

Comment: You don't need to import anything into the closure in JavaScript either. The article you link to uses it to ensure that the variable exists, and that assigning to it from the closure won't modify the global version. That is, it is copying the global variable to a local variable. The closure could use the global variable just fine.